# How can I print a pyramid of *

Tags: java

For example, enter a 5 and show this:

---

---

```
* * * * *     
  * * *       
    *
```

My current code is this:
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    int num = 4;

    while(num % 2 == 0){

        System.out.println("Introduce un numero impar:");
        num = in.nextInt();

        if (num % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println("Has introducido un numero par");
        }
    }

   for (int numFila = 0; numFila < num; numFila++) {    //filas
        for (int numColumna = 0; numColumna < num*2-1; numColumna++) {   //columnas

            if (numFila <= numColumna){
                System.out.print(" * ");
            }else{
                System.out.print("   ");
            }

        }
        //Salt de línia per començar un altre fila
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And what I can show is the following:

---

---

```
* * * * * * *   
  * * * * * *    
    * * * * *
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Answer (score 0):

just add `numColumna <= num - numFila - 1` to your if statement.
the whole code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 4;
        while(num % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero impar:");
            num = in.nextInt();
            if (num % 2 == 0){
                System.out.println("Has introducido un numero par");
            }
        }
        for (int numFila = 0; numFila < num; numFila++) {    //filas
            for (int numColumna = 0; numColumna < num*2-1; numColumna++) {   //columnas
                if (numFila <= numColumna && numColumna <= num - numFila - 1){
                    System.out.print(" * ");
                }else{
                    System.out.print("   ");
                }
            }
            //Salt de línia per començar un altre fila
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write the code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = 4;

    while(num % 2 == 0){

        System.out.println("Introduce un numero impar:");
        num = in.nextInt();

        if (num % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println("Has introducido un numero par");
        }
    }

    int rows = (num + 1) / 2;

    for(int i = rows; i >= 1; i--) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= rows - i; j++) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }

        for(int j=i; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(" * ");
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(" * ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```